# URL rewriting in tomcat 7 when hitting domain name

Tags: java, tomcat

I need help in redirecting URL for an application deployed in tomcat7.

When we use "www.portal.com/portal", am able to view the site.

I want to view the page by just entering the URL as "www.portal.com". So, i need help in what need to be modified in tomcat7 configuration to get this done.

Comment: You can name your application `ROOT` or change the path to your application in tomcat's  server.xml file.

Comment: You may take a look at http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/4.0/index.html

Comment: You could use [this](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) it uses Java Web Filters. Or use Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can name your application `ROOT` or change the path to your application in tomcat's server.xml file.
This is an example of a mapping in the `server.xml` file:

```
<Context docBase="portal" path="/portal" reloadable="true"
                source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:portal" />
```

To load the `portal` application without using `/portal` you need to change it to:

```
<Context docBase="portal" path="" reloadable="true"
                source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:portal" />
```

Comment: i am not seeing docBase in server.xml instead iam seeing appBase in that file

Comment: @user4130072 `appBase` is by default `webapps` and is the folder where you put the applications that you want to deploy. The `<Context>` elements are present only after you've deployed an application. You need to deploy your application before you can change its `path`

Comment: I am checking servlet.xml after deployment still i am not seeing <context> element. So, I added manually and i am not seeing any changes. ALso, what the source attribute refers. I am not using eclipse for deployment.

Comment: @user4130072 You need to restart the server after you modify `server.xml` if it still doesn't work, try the other approach, rename your application to `ROOT.war`